# Congratulations to Nick for reaching 1000 Points!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

Everyone please congratulate [Nick](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/3766/nick?tab=profile) for reaching the 1000 point threshold! Great accomplishment @Nick! Keep up the great work :D

Comment: Well done Nick!

Comment: Nicely done Nick!